# In Microsoft Excel, is it possible to automatically obtain the sum of the cells which have a common merged cell next to them?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

[Manual additions for illustration purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XKWp.png)

I am looking for a formula that would give me —

- in cell C1, the sum of B1 and B2, as the two cells have the merged cell A1 next to them;
- in cell C3, the sum of B3, B4 and B5, as the three cells have the merged cell A3 next to them;
- in cell C6, the sum of B6, B7, B8, B9, as the four cells have the merged cell A6 next to them, and so on.

Is there any such formula?

Answer (score 0):

Could the cells of colum C be **merged** as column A?

If yes, you may refer to my following steps.

1. Select column A, choose the Format Painter, apply the format to column C.
2. Enter the formula `=SUM(B1:$B$1000)-SUM(C2:$C$1000)` in the select range of column C.
3. Press Ctrl + Enter.

[image]